# How can I use BeautifulSoup or Slimit on a site to output the email address from a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, python, email, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have this example website: http://www.example.com/whatever.asp?profile=1

For each profile number I have a different email in this Java script code.

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function something()
{
var ptr;
ptr = "";
ptr += "<table><td class=france></td></table>";
ptr += "<table><td class=france><a href=mailto:exa";
ptr += "mple@email.com>email</a></td></table>";
document.all.something.innerHTML = ptr;
}
</script>
```

I want to parse or regex the email address. The position of emails depends on length. However with this python code only I can parse mple@email.com and not example@email.com

```
url=urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/whatever.asp?profile=1')
contents= url.read()   
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
js_content= soup.findAll("script")[0].text
reg = '(<)?(\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(?(1)>)'
match= re.search(reg,js_content)
print match.group()
```

Any help?  Thanks.

Comment: Directly use a parser or regex to extract the emails.

Comment: url=urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/whatever.asp?profile=1')
contents= url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
js_content= soup.findAll("script")[0].text
reg = '(<)?(\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(?(1)>)'
match= re.search(reg,js_content)
print match.group()

Comment: With this code only parse mple@email.com  but no example@email.com                                                           Any help?

Comment: use re.findall instead of search. Search would return only the first match.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = '''
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function something()
{
var ptr;
ptr = "";
ptr += "<table><td class=france></td></table>";
ptr += "<table><td class=france><a href=";
ptr += "mailto:example@knesset.com>email</a></td></table>";
document.all.something.innerHTML = ptr;
}
</script>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(soup)

for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    reg = '(<)?(\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(?(1)>)'
    reg2 = 'mailto:.*'
    secondHalf= re.search(reg, script.text)
    firstHalf= re.search(reg2, script.text)
    secondHalfEmail = secondHalf.group()
    firstHalfEmail = firstHalf.group()
    firstHalfEmail = firstHalfEmail.replace('mailto:', '')
    firstHalfEmail = firstHalfEmail.replace('";', '')
    if firstHalfEmail == secondHalfEmail:
        email = secondHalfEmail
    else:
        if ('>') not in firstHalfEmail:
            if ('>') not in secondHalfEmail:
                if firstHalfEmail != secondHalfEmail:
                    email = firstHalfEmail + secondHalfEmail
            else:
                email = firstHalfEmail
        else:
            email = secondHalfEmail

    print email
```

Comment: I get  mple@email.com but not example@email.com

Comment: Yeah i just realized that...fixed it

Comment: I have another question. Is your script working also for this       ptr += "homer@email.com>email</a></td></table>"                                                       homer@email.com ?

Comment: Not currently...I can fix it...hold on

Comment: I mean ptr += "<mailto:homer@email.com>email</a></td></table>";    an parse             homer@email.com

Comment: Well if there is no mailto: then the regex wont return anything so yes. But if theres a random char after mailto: then no

Comment: there is not random char after mailto:         then should work :)

Comment: I get : example@microsoft.com>email</a></td></table>example@microsoft.com

Comment: ptr += "<table><td class=france></td></table>";
ptr += "<table><td class=france><a href=";
ptr += "mailto:example@microsoft.com>email</a></td></table>";

Comment: I change a bit of code. I'm trying all positions for email but that one is not working yet.

Comment: I updated it...but you should really open another question if it is not working for other situations. I can help there too. I already answered the questions and now were getting a bit off the question topic :) which is fine! but not in SO's eyes

Comment: Thank you very much heinst for your help. I will open a new post. for another situation and I think is the last case.

Comment: My new problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690305/javascript-variable-with-html-code-regex-email-matching

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `re.findall` instead of `re.search` because search would return only the first match.

```
url=urllib.urlopen('http://www.example.com/whatever.asp?profile=1')
contents= url.read()   
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
js_content= soup.findAll("script")[0].text
reg = r'<?(\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+)>?'
match= re.findall(reg,js_content)
```