# Javascript variable with html code regex email matching

Tags: javascript, python, regex, email, beautifulsoup

This python script is not working to output the email address example@email.com for this case.

This was my previous post.

[How can I use BeautifulSoup or Slimit on a site to output the email address from a javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682751/how-can-i-use-beautifulsoup-or-slimit-on-a-site-to-output-the-email-address-from)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = '''
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function something()
{
var ptr;
ptr = "";
ptr += "<table><td class=france></td></table>";
ptr += "<table><td class=france><a href=mail";
ptr += "to:example@email.com>email</a></td></table>";
document.all.something.innerHTML = ptr;
}
</script>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(soup)

for script in soup.find_all('script'):
  reg = '(<)?(\w+@\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(?(1)>)'
  reg2 = 'mailto:.*'
  secondHalf= re.search(reg, script.text)
  firstHalf= re.search(reg2, script.text)
  secondHalfEmail = secondHalf.group()
  firstHalfEmail = firstHalf.group()
  firstHalfEmail = firstHalfEmail.replace('mailto:', '')
  firstHalfEmail = firstHalfEmail.replace('";', '')
  if firstHalfEmail == secondHalfEmail:
     email = secondHalfEmail
  else:
     if ('>') not in firstHalfEmail:
        if ('>') not in secondHalfEmail:
            if firstHalfEmail != secondHalfEmail:
                email = firstHalfEmail + secondHalfEmail
        else:
            email = firstHalfEmail
    else:
        email = secondHalfEmail

    print email
```

It would be nice if someone can help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you can't find "mailto" in your text, because the first half "mail" is not in the same line as the second half "to". To solve your problem properly only have to know the value of ptr at the end of this program.

I know that this is a bad way to do it, but if you are sure that the structure is always like this:

```
soup = """
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> function ...() 
{ var ptr; 
ptr = ""; 
ptr += "..."; 
ptr += "..."; 
ptr += "...";
document.all.something.innerHTML = ptr; 
}
</script> 
"""
```

You can use this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup)

for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    #This matches everything between "{ var ptr;" 
    #and "document"
    regex = "{ var ptr;(.*)document"
    code = re.search(regex, script.text, flags=re.DOTALL).groups()[0]
    #This is actually dangerous because anything 
    #in the code will be executed here, but if
    #it's like your example everything will 
    #work fine and you can access the value of ptr
    exec(code)
    print ptr
```

Now you can use either Beautifulsoup or re to parse ptr. If you don't how it's structured, you can use this:

```
    mail = re.search("<a href=mailto:(.*?)>", ptr).groups()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather interesting (I think) approach.

Instead of parsing this javascript code - **execute it**!

Get the `ptr` value, load it via `BeautifulSoup` and get the `href` attribute value from the `a` tag. Example using [`V8` engine](https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pyv8 import PyV8

data = """
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function something()
{
var ptr;
ptr = "";
ptr += "<table><td class=france></td></table>";
ptr += "<table><td class=france><a href=mail";
ptr += "to:example@email.com>email</a></td></table>";
document.all.something.innerHTML = ptr;
}
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

# prepare the function to return a value and add a function call
js_code = soup.script.text.strip().replace('document.all.something.innerHTML = ptr;', 'return ptr;') + "; something()"

ctxt = PyV8.JSContext()
ctxt.enter()

soup = BeautifulSoup(ctxt.eval(str(js_code)))
print soup.a['href'].split('mailto:')[1]
```

Prints:

```
example@email.com
```